# websocket mqtt with embedded activeMQ

Tags: servlets, websocket, jetty, activemq-classic, mqtt

I set up an ActiveMQ broker to serve as an MQTT-Broker over tcp and websockets as follows:

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.addConnector("mqtt://localhost:1883");
broker.addConnector("ws://0.0.0.0:1884");
broker.setPersistent(false);
broker.setBrokerName("default");
broker.start();
```

On my classpath I have the following jars (since I don't wanna have slf4j included):

```
activemq-broker-5.11.1.jar          activemq-stomp-5.11.1.jar
activemq-client-5.11.1.jar          activemq-web-5.11.1.jar
activemq-http-5.11.1.jar            commons-codec-1.6.jar
activemq-mqtt-5.11.1.jar            geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
activemq-openwire-legacy-5.11.1.jar     geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
activemq-parent-5.11.1              hawtbuf-1.11.jar
activemq-spring-5.11.1.jar          mqtt-client-1.10.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1-2.jar
jetty-all-9.2.8.v20150217.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5
logback-classic-1.0.13
logback-core-1.0.13
```

When I try to connect with the paho javascript client it hangs while my mosquitto clients manage to connect through tcp with no hassle.

In the logs I found this line:

```
DEBUG o.a.a.t.ws.jetty9. MQTTSocket - Waiting for StompSocket to be properly started...
```

Reading the code I found out that MQTTSocket (it's the same with StompSocket; tried both) is waiting for a CountDownLatch object that would be counted down only in doStart(). Apparently doStart() is never being called. Why? How can I call it? What am I missing?

My html / javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="shared/mqttws31-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    //sample HTML/JS script that will publish/subscribe to topics in the Google Chrome Console
    //by Matthew Bordignon @bordignon on twitter.

    var wsbroker = "127.0.0.1";  //mqtt websocket enabled broker
    var wsport = 1884 // port for above

    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport, "",
        "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

    client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
      console.log("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
    };

    client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
      console.log(message.destinationName, ' -- ', message.payloadString);
    };

    var options = {
      timeout: 300,
      //mqttVersion: 3, // to constrain the protocol to version 3
      onSuccess: function () {
        console.log("mqtt connected");
        // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic, you can add multile lines of these
        client.subscribe('/World', {qos: 1});


        //use the below if you want to publish to a topic on connect
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
        message.destinationName = "/World";
        client.send(message);

      },
      onFailure: function (message) {
        console.log("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
      }
    };

  function init() {
      client.connect(options);
  }

    </script>
  </head>
  <h1>MQTT test</h1>
  <body onload="init();">
  </body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**:
I also tried the xbeans config with an adapted xml file that comes with activeMQ:

```
System.setProperty("activemq.conf", "conf");
System.setProperty("activemq.data", "data");

BrokerService broker;
try {
    broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker("xbean:activemq.xml");
    broker.start();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

XML files:

- activemq.xml:
  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9632359/activemq.xml
- jetty.xml: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9632359/jetty.xml

Comment: Using jetty8 it is able to connect independently of toggling an additional line 27:"      mqttVersion: 3," on and off. But then still no messages can be sent or received. Still thinking it's a config issue, probably even with jetty?

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess `broker.addConnector("ws://0.0.0.0:1884");` 
   should be `broker.addConnector("ws://localhost:1884");`
2. I've written and successfully run a `BrokerService` with **mqtt** and also with **ws**, from where I suspect you're missing `websocket-server`

Be careful that `jetty-all` and `websocket-server` versions depend on `activemq-http` version. These are my **gradle** dependencies:

```
  compile group: "org.apache.activemq",  version: "5.11.+", name: "activemq-all"

  compile group: "org.apache.activemq",  version: "5.11.+", name: "activemq-mqtt"

  compile group: "org.apache.activemq",  version: "5.11.+", name: "activemq-http"

  compile group: "org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate",  version: "8.+", name: "jetty-all"  

  compile group: "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket",  version: "9.+", name: "websocket-server"
```

3. You can specify individual connector properties such as name with this:

TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();

```
connector = new TransportConnector();
connector.setUri(new URI("mqtt://localhost:1883"));
connector.setName("MQTTConn");
broker.addConnector(connector);

connector = new TransportConnector();
connector.setUri(new URI("ws://localhost:1884"));
connector.setName("WSConn");
broker.addConnector(connector);
```

Comment: Teixi, thank you for the answer! I tried (1); both "0.0.0.0" and "localhost" work. For (2 and 3): When I unpack my jetty-all (8 and 9) there is a websocket folder. I managed to get it work with jetty8. Jetty9 seems not to work for now. Unfortunately. I will try it with activemq-6.

Answer (score 0):

I added 4 lines of code to activemq and it works now. Not sure yet if it's gonna be included, at least I issued it in the bug tracker: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5784 
patch: http://pastebin.com/phcsJHR5